# associate cakephp model to non-cakephp database table

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

is it possible to create a model in a CakePHP application and associate that model with a database table that is not associated with a cakePHP application at all?

For example, that database table belongs to another application and we want to create a model in CakePHP that uses that table (so that table is not conforming to CakePHP's convention at all). How do I do this? What do I need to put in my Model in order for that association to work WITHOUT changing my table (I need to be able to perform the basic CRUD operations on that table)

Any idea please?

thank you

Comment: Show us what the table looks like, and we might be able to help...

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that. For example if you have a cand table with idCandidat primary key,you create a model and use the $useTable & $primaryKey properties :

```
class Candidat extends AppModel{
var $name = 'Candidats';
var $useTable = 'cand';
var $primaryKey  = 'idCandidat';
//etc.
}
```

and you continue using your model in controller like you'll be doing with a normal one.

Answer (score 0):

You can even use a table that is in a totally different Database or on a different server. For this you can use (I will just extend @chroonoss 's example as it is correct):

```
class Candidat extends AppModel{
var $name = 'Candidats';
var $useTable = 'cand';
var $primaryKey  = 'idCandidat';

var $usedbConfig = 'external';
}
```

This will allow you to use a different DataSource connetion. These are defined in:
 `app/config/database.php`. You have to have a property named "external" there for this example to work:

```
public $external = array(
        'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => '101.180.10.17',
        'login' => 'username',
        'password' => 'yourTopSecretPassword',
        'database' => 'database_name',
        'prefix' => '',
        'encoding' => 'utf8',
    );
```

Of course you can name your DataSource as you like.

Comment: What if I want to change the name of the fields of my model (for example, let's say there was a field called `phone` in the database but I want the model to refer to that field as `telephone`). How would I go about doing that? And what if I don't want to use all the columns in my table for my model (let's say I just want to associate a few columns of my table to my model). How would I do that?

Comment: Just alter the Model::find() calls to include: 'fields' => array('field1', 'field2', 'field3'). This way the return of the find() function will contain only the fields listed. I personally do not know any other way to alter that in a model itself. Check this out:
http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1017/Retrieving-Your-Data

Answer (score 0):

You can set fields (columns) in find function - http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1018/find
Or if you want to set fields to association, you can do this:

```
var $belongsTo = array(
  'User' => array(
    'className' => 'User',
    'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
    'fields' => array('name','phone')
   )
);
```